# How to make RewriteRule in this case

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried this.

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+).html$ article/List/$1/$2 [L]
```

My current URL is: `domain.com/article/List/234/article-title`

I would like this after rewrite `domain.com/article/article-title`

Comment: The `1` is supposed to be dynamic, some sort of record ID presumably? Then you _can not_ rewrite from `/article/article-title` to `/article/List/1/article-title` using mod_rewrite - the server has no way of determining what the value of that ID should be at this point, based on the information that _is_ available.

Comment: Maybe you made wrong comment, I would like to /article/List/1/article-title to  /article/article-title. The 1 is article number and it's dynamic number.

Comment: You would “like to” … _what_? There’s something missing after that. If you are _trying_ to say, that you want to call `/article/article-title` in your browser, and have that rewritten to `/article/List/1/article-title` internally - then my comment is absolutely spot-on.

Comment: So, read my first comment again then – what don’t you get about this?

Comment: _“I would like this after rewrite”_ - just to be clear, by that you mean, this is the URL you want to see in your browser address bar, yes?

Comment: yes..., exactly

Comment: Okay, so say one of your new URLs was supposed to be `/article/foobar`. Can you tell me, what numeric ID that article `foobar` is supposed to have in the re-written URL - without looking that up in your database? If not - then how do you expect the server to determine it at this point?